# Show that $\cup_{n=1,2,3...}(-1+1/n,0)=(-1,1)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there a mistake in this question? I think, it cannot equal to $(-1,1)$.

Comment: yeah there must be a mistake

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a mistake. it should be $(-1,0)$ on the right.

Or perhaps the left hand side is $(-1+1/n,1)$ rather than $(-1+1/n,0)$.